# S3 getPresignedUrl Invalid access key in Nodejs with Cognito user

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I'm getting a presignedUrl for an S3 bucket (.opus file) from the following function:

> function GetRecordingURL(bucket, filePath, accessToken)
> {

```
AWS.config.update({ 
    accessKeyId: accessToken,
    secretAccessKey: accessToken,
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
    region: 'eu-west-2'
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: filePath,
    Expires: 60000
}

console.log("Bucket:",bucket);
console.log("Filepath:",filePath);
console.log("AccessToken:",accessToken);   

const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params)

console.log("URL:", url);
return url;
```

}

it generates the URL fine, but when I browse it I get the message:

[image]

I'm setting the accessKeyId and the secretAccessKey to the same values (accessToken) and I think this might be the issue? I'm using Cognito and logging in like this:

```
try {
      console.log("Auth", Auth);
      const user = await Auth.signIn(this.state.username, this.state.password);
      console.log(user);
      this.props.auth.setAuthStatus(true);
      this.props.auth.setUser(user);
      this.props.history.push("/SearchScreen");
    }catch(error) {
      let err = null;
      !error.message ? err = { "message": error } : err = error;
      this.setState({
        errors: {
          ...this.state.errors,
          cognito: err
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

then using user.signInUserSession.getAccessToken().getJwtToken() to get the token. Is there another token I should be using?

Comment: For some reason, you have set both access key and secret key to the same value of `accessToken`. That's never going to work. Do you have access to real IAM user or STS credentials? Or can you make API calls to a backend that has IAM/STS credentials that itself can pre-sign the URL?

Comment: You can use the Cognito service to [deliver STS credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html) to your application. Those STS credentials can be used to pre-sign S3 URLs. Note that the underlying IAM role associated with the Cognito user's [identity pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html) must have the relevant underlying IAM permissions e.g. s3:GetObject if you are signing a GET URL.

Comment: OK, so I need to read up on STS creds then!

Comment: Yes, assuming that you can exchange your Cognito identify for a set of STS credentials and those credentials have the requisite S3 permissions then they can be used to pre-sign a URL. As you know, all pre-signed URLs are time-limited so bear that in mind for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html), you can only create pre-signed URLs with an IAM user rather than Cognito user.

Comment: I was wondering if it was that, so will try it this morning - thank you!